# Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, onclicklistener

I'm trying to close some custom softkeyboard, whenever a listview is clicked. However, android apparently does not allow to set Click Listeners for a complete ListView. The following line

```
listview.setOnClickListener { softkeyboard?.hideContent() }
```

Results in an exception, telling me to

> Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView

The Listview is wrapped in an LinearLayout. If I set the listener on this LinearLayout, it does not receive any click events. Also using

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> softkeyboard?.hideContent() }
```

does not solve the problem: it only works for direct clisk on items, while the List has vast areas where no item is visible, but a background. The click on the background should work as well.

Comment: did u try adding android:clickable = "true" to your root of listview layout

Comment: override `View#performClick` then

Comment: You need to disable click events on listView and it's children, then  enable clicks for LinearLayout

Comment: try to use clicklistener to parent view.

Comment: I believe i had tried clickable="true", which didn't solve the problem. Also setting a click listener on parent view does not work - the click isn't triggered, but apparently consumed by the Listview for scrolling. My current workaround is a custom viewgroup ´ClickableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout´ which overrides onInterceptTouchEvent - that might be similar to what @psink has suggested.